# Local Pip install not able to import any classes within the package

Tags: python, deployment, pip, setuptools, pypi

I have a python package which I built from

```
python setup.py sdist
```

The package name is : Yify

I installed this using

```
pip3 install .
```

After this when I open the python3 interpreter and `import Yify` , it imports successfully but it doesn't seem to include the main python file inside the dist_packages/Yify directory .

Here is the folder structure :-

```
├── dist
│   └── Yify-1.0.tar.gz
├── get-pip.py
├── LICENSE
├── README.rst
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── Yify
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── venv
|   ├── Yify.py
```

The Yify.py contains `yify` class .
When i do

```
import Yify
Yify.yify()
```

It gives me 'yify' not found error ! .

hOW TO fix it ?

Here is the setup.py contents:-

```
import platform
from setuptools import setup

install_requires = ['bs4' , 'urllib3' ]


setup(
    name='Yify',
    packages = ['Yify'] ,
    version = 'v1.0',
    description = '''
    This Module is used to get the Top seeded torrents at any given time and get the entire movie details and ratings . 
    Its also useful to search for any movie using different parameters and obtain their magnet link or torrent file of any prefered quality.
''' ,
    author = 'Natesh M Bhat' ,
    url = 'https://github.com/nateshmbhat/Yify-Python',
    author_email = 'nateshmbhatofficial@gmail.com' ,
    # download_url = 'https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/archive/v2.6.tar.gz',
    keywords=['yify','torrent-python' , 'movie-torrent' , 'torrent' , 'pyyify' , 'Yify' , 'yify torrent' , 'yify download' , 'download yify' , 'yifyer'  , 'yifypy' , 'torrent download' , 'movie torrent' , 'movie downloader', 'movie finder'],
    classifiers = [] ,
    install_requires=install_requires
)
```

Also When I directly go into the python3.6 distpackages/Yify folder and execute python3 from there. Everything works fine .

Also dir(Yify) return only the below fields

```
dir(Yify)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

Comment: you shouldn't need to call `setup.py` may i ask why you didn't just do `pip install yify`

Comment: Its not in the pypi repository , Its my python library which is local. To upload to Pip first , i was testing it before uploading.

Comment: try using pip install -e "Path where you downloaded locally"

Comment: try using pip install -e "Path where you downloaded locally"

Comment: Ya tried it . same thing.

Comment: I can see my Yify.py file in the distpackages directory and when go to that folder and import Yify.py from there , it works fine . But when i am executing python3 from other folders its not woking

Comment: Found a temporary fix .  in the `__int__.py`  i wrote  `from . import Yify` . So while accessing i do Yify.Yify.yify() to get my classese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `__init__.` must be called `__init__.py`.
2. When you do `import Yify` you only import `Yify/__init__.py`, not `Yify/Yify.py` unless it's imported in `__init__.py`.
3. To fix you import do: `from Yify import Yify`. That way you really import `Yify/Yify.py`.